# Need solution for insert multiple rows in table from comma separated string. I am able to insert in table with one column

Tags: sql-server

```
Declare @Var varchar(MAX)
        Set @Var = '1,2,3'
        DECLARE @XML AS XML
        DECLARE @Delimiter AS CHAR(1) =','
        SET @XML = CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@Var,@Delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML)      

    Declare @Var1 nvarchar(MAX)
    Set @Var1 = '10,11,12'
    DECLARE @XML1 AS XML
    DECLARE @Delimiter1 AS CHAR(1) =','
    SET @XML1 = CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@Var1,@Delimiter1 ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML)
DECLARE @temp TABLE (ID INT,ID1 INT);
    INSERT INTO @temp (ID,ID1) values   

    (SELECT N.value('.', 'INT') AS ID FROM @XML.nodes('X') AS T(N),
    SELECT N1.value('.', 'INT') AS ID1 FROM @XML1.nodes('X') AS T(N1))

    select * from  @temp
```

Comment: This is not a question. It's a code dump. Please [edit] it to provide a question that someone that doesn't read your mind, have no clue what you are trying to do and does not have any idea about how the target table look like can answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have two comma separated values but there is no relation between them. I am writing below `SQl` query using `Row_number` function and joining two comma separated results arbitrary. Please check -

```
Declare @Var varchar(MAX)
    Set @Var = '1,2,3'

    DECLARE @XML AS XML
    DECLARE @Delimiter AS CHAR(1) =','
    SET @XML = CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@Var,@Delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML)

    Declare @Var1 nvarchar(MAX)
    Set @Var1 = '10,11,12'

    DECLARE @XML1 AS XML
    DECLARE @Delimiter1 AS CHAR(1) =','
    SET @XML1 = CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@Var1,@Delimiter1 ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML)

    DECLARE @temp TABLE (ID INT,ID1 INT);

    INSERT INTO @temp (ID,ID1)
    SELECT
        X.ID, Y.ID1
    from
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowId,N.value('.', 'INT') AS ID FROM @XML.nodes('X') AS T(N)) as X
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowId,N1.value('.', 'INT') AS ID1 FROM @XML1.nodes('X') AS T(N1)) as Y
        ON X.RowId = Y.RowId

    SELECT * FROM  @temp
```

Note - There is some issues with above query i.e, first value of first comma separated string can join with third value of second comma separated string.